# OVH DKIM Record Not Found

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, dkim, ovh

I set up a DKIM Record on my OVH VPS recently.

The ultimate record generated is as follows (public key overwritten):

```
v=DKIM1;g=*;h=sha256;k=rsa;s=email;p=AVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYYYBBIIIIIIIIIIGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEECCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCRRRRRRRRRRRRRREEEEEEEEEEEET;t=y:s;
```

No errors show when I set up this DNS record.

But the problem is that when I check the existence of the newly-created DKIM record with an [online validator](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx) I just see:

```
No DKIM Record found
```

I had a similar problem with the DMARC record till an online trawl showed me that you have to put _dmarc in as the subdomain on the configuration form you fill in when creating the DMARC record.

Maybe something similar applies to OVH's DKIM records but OVH isn't offering any help to its vanilla VPS hosting customers.

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: "Ideas appreciated." 1) Ask your provider 2) Specifically because you don't give the name involved so noone can help you and 3) you obfuscate something that is PUBLIC by definition, so... Use DNSViz online troubleshooting tool to check your DNS configuration, or else go back to 1). Considering your point about `_dmarc` which should have been "obvious" from the get go, maybe you need to contact your email provider to get more advice on how to setup email related DNS records.

Comment: you may want maybe to read more in the Help section about how this website works... It is not a forum but a Q&A site, and there is no one moderator. Your question attracted 5 different negative points, from 5 different people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when validating a DKIM record, there's a check made to both the DKIM record in the DNS Zone **and the mail server on the associated domain name**. The mail server therefore needs to be apprised of the location of the private key complementing the public key in the DKIM record.

In my situation, i.e. using a VPS with a self-installed mail server like Postfix, the standard approach is to also install a package called **opendkim** on the VPS server. This package can be used to generate key pairs and interface with Postfix on the location of the private key. It works too.

Refer to [this description](https://blog.matrixpost.net/set-up-spf-and-dkim-for-postfix-on-ubuntu/) for elaboration.